# Serializing IHttpRequest in ExceptionHandler terminates the service

Tags: servicestack

I have this piece of code in my host base' Configure:

```
    ExceptionHandler = (httpReq, httpRes, operationName, ex) =>
    {
        try
        {
           string req = httpReq.ToJsv();
        }
        catch
        {
        }

    };
```

The attempt to serialize httpReq just terminates the service, despite that its being wrapped in try/catch.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to serialize self-referencing control objects (i.e. like HttpRequest/HttpResponse) as it likely got itself into a recursive loop. You can avoid recursive loops by setting a `JsConfig.MaxDepth`, but the recommendation is to avoid serializing objects with cyclical dependencies.

Comment: What made me wonder is why there was no exception thrown - not even StackOverflow ?